# Django using custom SQL instead of models to return JSON object to template

Tags: python, mysql, json, django

I currently am able to retrieve JSON data/object from my models.py and MySQL database and send that JSON object to my template. How would I be able to use custom SQL to retrieve data from MySQL then make it into a JSON object to send to my template. I basically don't want to use models.py at all. Here is what I have in my views.py when I am using models.py:

```
def startpage(request):
    platforms = Platform.objects.select_related().values('platformtype')
    return render(request, 'HTML1.html', {'platforms_as_json' : json.dumps(list(platforms)),})
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def my_custom_sql(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT platformtype FROM Platform", [self.Platform])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    return row
```

How would I be able to do the same thing except without using models.py and using custom SQL queries within my views? Thank you

UPDATE:

```
def startpage(request):
    platforms = my_custom_sql()
    return render(request, 'Html1.html', {'platforms_as_json' : json.dumps(list(platforms)), })


def my_custom_sql():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT HWPlatformName FROM hwplatform", None)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows
```

Now I am able to get the data onto my template but I don't believe it is giving me correct JSON format..

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using models? It's one of the selling point of using Django (with migrations)

Comment: (1.) Have you looked at [Django's docs on emitting raw SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/)? (2.) What Emile said

Comment: I know, I was using them previously and models made life so easy. I will need to write other scripts for my web application and don't want to rely Django models. And yes, I have looked at the docs.

Comment: You can use Django models in outside scripts so that's not a very convincing reason.

Comment: true but this is more of a learning experience. I also would like to not have all of the django and admin tables created inside the MySQL database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want instances of the Model, you're looking for the [`raw`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/sql/) method on the objects property.

```
platforms = Platform.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM Platform')
```

If you're just looking for content from the server, then you can just return the value from the SQL query:

```
platforms = my_custom_sql() # Or call my_custom_sql statically.
```

If you're looking for delayed population, you can put the `yield` statement into your `my_custom_sql` function.

Comment: I think the raw method gives you a model object, correct?

Comment: My goal is to not use any model objects. Is that possible?

Comment: @Carbon Does the addendum help?

Comment: I have tried platforms = my_custom_sql() but it gives me the error when I try running my Django server. It says that "my_custom_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Comment: If my database has a table named "Platform" and columns "Platform_ID" and "platformtype"